# How to show search results for all open buffers

Tags: search, multiple-files

One thing I often do (but rely on the command line to do) is searching/grepping in multiple files.

**Is there a way to display search results for all the open buffers?**

Ideally, I'd like to have a new split buffer containing result location and snippet much like `grep` does. For example (`/statistics`):

```
models/statistics.php: /*! \file   statistics.php
controllers/stats.php: $this->load->model('statistics');
controllers/stats.php: // Query statistics...
controllers/stats.php: $num_exams = $this->statistics->countExams();
```

As a bonus, I'd like to be able to search for the term under the cursor, pretty much like `gd` does.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11975174/how-do-i-search-the-open-buffers-in-vim

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use `:vimgrep /pattern/ {files}` to populate the quickfix list with matching patterns. The problem is that `:vimgrep` files option doesn't directly allow for buffers. You can use:

```
%   Is replaced with the current file name.       *:_%* *c_%*
#   Is replaced with the alternate file name.     *:_#* *c_#*
#n  (where n is a number) is replaced with        *:_#0* *:_#n*
    the file name of buffer n.  "#0" is the same as "#".     *c_#n*
##  Is replaced with all names in the argument list   *:_##* *c_##*
    concatenated, separated by spaces.  Each space in a name
    is preceded with a backslash.
#<n (where n is a number > 0) is replaced with old    *:_#<* *c_#<*
    file name n.  See |:oldfiles| or |v:oldfiles| to get the
    number.                         *E809*
    {only when compiled with the |+eval| and |+viminfo| features}
```

Another option is to write a script that generates a file list from `:buffers`. Per [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271364/variable-that-holds-list-of-all-open-buffers-in-vim) with a slight tweek we get:

```
function! BuffersList()
  let all = range(0, bufnr('$'))
  let res = []
  for b in all
    if buflisted(b)
      call add(res, bufname(b))
    endif
  endfor
  return res
endfunction

function! GrepBuffers (expression)
  exec 'vimgrep/'.a:expression.'/ '.join(BuffersList())
endfunction

command! -nargs=+ GrepBufs call GrepBuffers(<q-args>)
```

You can now call `:GrepBufs <expression>` and get the standard `:vimgrep` output but using the buffers instead.

**Update** If you would like to call `GrepBuffers` using the value under the cursor add this new mapping.

```
nnoremap <leader>z :call GrepBuffers("<C-R><C-W>")<CR>
```

When you are in normal mode type `<leader>z` and you'll `:vimgrep` the cursor word over your open buffers.

Comment: In single line form: `command! -bang -nargs=+ Bufgrep execute 'vimgrep<bang><args> ' . join(map(filter(range(1, bufnr('$')), 'buflisted(v:val)'), '"#".v:val'), ' ')`. Usage: `:Bufgrep/foo/`

Answer (score 13):

Searching in only opened buffers is nice, but there may come a time where you want to search across an entire project. It can be faster and easier than you think!

#### Searching across a project

- `grep` is the Unix standard search tool. Worth mentioning due to its ubiquity. Already integrated into Vim via `:grep` command. e.g. `:grep -r 'foo'`. See `:h :grep`.
- [Ack](http://beyondgrep.com/) is faster than regular grep because it skips VCS directories, binary files, and can search for specific type of filetypes like `--perl`. For Vim integration see [Ack.vim](https://github.com/mileszs/ack.vim)
- [Ag the Silver Surfer](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher) is a code-searching tool similar to ack, but faster. Vim plugin: [Ag.vim](https://github.com/rking/ag.vim)
- `git grep` searches a repository very quickly. [Fugitive.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive) provides `:Ggrep`.
- [Ripgrep](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep) is even faster than Ag and `git grep`. Can be used with `:grep` as well.

I recommend both ripgrep, Ag, and `git grep` as they are all super fast. I have searched over 4700+ in less than a 1 second. It's pretty hard to beat ripgrep.

To test out one of these alternatives without a plugin or you simply don't want a plugin you can set your `'grepprg'` option accordingly. e.g. `set grepprg=ag\ --vimgrep` or `set grepprg=rg\ --vimgrep`. See `:h 'grepprg'` and `:h 'grepformat'` for more information. Now you can search via `:grep`. e.g. `:grep 'foo'`.

As a final fallback you can use `:vimgrep` as it is available on all systems that Vim is available. See `:h :vimg` for more help.

#### QuickFix List

As most of these options use the quickfix list I suggest you use some more friendly mappings to transverse the quickfix list. I use Tim Pope's [unimpaired](https://github.com/tpope/vim-unimpaired) plugin which uses `]q` and `[q` for `:cnext` and `:cprev` respectively. Some people like the quickfix to open after a search is performed then add the following to your `~/.vimrc` file: `autocmd QuickFixCmdPost *grep* cwindow`. You can also manually open the QuickFix list via `:copen`.

#### Want even faster "searches"?

You are going to need to use some tool that uses a prebuilt indexes like [ctags](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/), [cscope](http://cscope.sourceforge.net/), or [GNU global](http://www.gnu.org/software/global/manual/global.html).

- Vim has built in ctag support via `:tag`, `<c-]>`, and many other commands and options. See `:h tags`. Also may want to read [Effortless Ctags with Git](http://tbaggery.com/2011/08/08/effortless-ctags-with-git.html) or look into the [Gutentags](https://github.com/ludovicchabant/vim-gutentags) plugin
- Cscope support is also built in and can be used via `:cscope` command. See `:h cscope`

#### More help

I would start with this nice [Vimcast](http://vimcasts.org/) episode: [Search multiple files with `:vimgrep`](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/search-multiple-files-with-vimgrep/).

For more Vim help see the documentation:

```
:h grep
:h :vimgrep
:h :grep
:h 'grepprg'
:h 'grepformat'
:h quickfix
:h :cnext
:h tags
:h cscope
```

Answer (score 8):

#### Commands [`:bufdo`](https://vimhelp.org/windows.txt.html#%3Abufdo) and [`:vimgrepadd`](https://vimhelp.org/quickfix.txt.html#%3Avimgrepadd)

This answer is based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/11976158/1057593.

However, I wanted add a few bits. Again the basic command is

```
:bufdo vimgrepadd pattern %
```

If your quickfix list is not empty, you probably want to clear it first. This can be done with [`:cexpr`](https://vimhelp.org/quickfix.txt.html#E777)

```
:cexpr []
```

**Mappings to cycle through matches**

[vim-unimpaired](https://github.com/tpope/vim-unimpaired) provides the mappings `]q` and `[q` to cycle through the matches.

**Workflow with the command line history**

It is a convenient workflow to enter the search pattern separately with `/pattern`. This allows you to use a generic command from your command line history using the current search pattern. This would look like

```
/pattern
:bufdo vimgrepadd // %
```

A typical new buffer wide search would be

```
/pattern2
:bufdo<up><up>...
```

I have added following mappings to my vimrc to use `<C-N>` and `<C-P>` instead of the arrow keys to stay with my hands on the home row

```
cmap <C-P> <Up>
cmap <C-N> <Down>
```

Note searching the command line history `q:` with `/bufdo<CR>` interferes with using the current search pattern. You could use `:keepp /bufdo<cr>`.

For more details on the command line history see the help pages [`:h history`](https://vimhelp.org/cmdline.txt.html#history) and [`:h cmdline-window`](https://vimhelp.org/cmdline.txt.html#cmdline-window) and https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Using_command-line_history.

You can add to the reusable command [`:copen`](https://vimhelp.org/quickfix.txt.html#%3Acopen) to immediately see the quickfix list in the following way:

```
:execute "bufdo vimgrepadd // %" | copen
```

The proposal from stackoverflow `:bufdo vimgrepadd // % | copen` opened several unintended windows in my case.

And with `:cexpr []` the reusable command would become

```
:execute "cexpr [] | bufdo vimgrepadd // %" | copen
```

Answer (score 7):

My [GrepCommands plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4173) defines variants of the built-in `:vimgrep` command which target all arguments, listed buffers, windows in the current tab page or all tab
pages for its search. Basically, a robust plugin implementation of @jecxjo's answer.